# what is the basic difference between jobconf and job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

hi i wanted to know the basic difference between jobconf and  job objects,currently i am submitting my job like this

```
JobClient.runJob(jobconf);
```

i saw other way of submitting jobs like this

```
Configuration conf = getConf();
Job job = new Job(conf, "secondary sort");
job.waitForCompletion(true);     
return 0;
```

and how can i specify the sortcomparator class for the job using jobconf?

can any one explain me this concept?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In short: `JobConf` and everything else in the `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` package is part of the old API used to write hadoop jobs, `Job` and everything in the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package is part of the new and preferred API to write hadoop jobs. Both APIs generally provide equivalent core functionality.

If you're new to hadoop just start using the new API (i.e. `Job` and `Configuration` instead of `JobConf`). Make sure to not import anything from the `mapred` package. When you find examples on the internet using the old API you can use [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api) or [this guide](http://hadoopbeforestarting.blogspot.de/2012/12/difference-between-hadoop-old-api-and.html) to translate it to the new API.

Answer (score 3):

In old API job configuration is done by JobConf object. In the new API, job configuration is done through a Configuration object.

Job control is performed through the Job class in the new API, rather than the old
JobClient, which no longer exists in the new API.