# How to wait for job completition in hadoop 1.2.1?

Tags: object, hadoop, configuration, wait, jobs

I am using hadoop 1.2.1 to develop mapreduce programs. I look in hadoop 1.2.1 many of them or in general use `JobConf` Object to operate the driver class. And then I need `waitforcompletition` function that belongs to `Job` Object.

So should I use 2 object's `JobConf` and `Job` in one driver class? or I just use only `Job` ? Or how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the basic difference between jobconf and job?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402360/what-is-the-basic-difference-between-jobconf-and-job)

Comment: thanks bro firstly for your answer, it's true if jobConf is old and job is new. So I use the old one, because I need it's distributed cache feature that use jobConf. So in your opinnion, how can I create wait for completion or anything with the same function with jobConf? Thanks bro, I need your suggest....