# What is jobConf class?What does it do?

Tags: java, python, hadoop

I am new to hadoop. I don't know what jobConf class is doing inside driver class.
Please explain complete statement of creating the conf object.

Comment: check java doc- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it's a map/reduce job configuration. 
Check out this link:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html

also here you can find intresting facts:

[what is the basic difference between jobconf and job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402360/what-is-the-basic-difference-between-jobconf-and-job)